# TeamCity (or Jenkins) with Cluster/Replicated servers

Tags: high-availability, failover, failovercluster, jenkins, teamcity

We use Team City 7 for Continuous Intergration.  Sometimes I need to bring down the server for maintenance which stirs up complaints.  Is anyone using a cluster for these types of servers where there is one database instance, but perhaps a failover cluster for the front end (Tomcat) application servers so that I can take down a server without disrupting service?  I am running it on Windows Server 2008 R2 but I am open to Linux solutions as well.

Comment: TC stores a lot of data on the filesystem (build configurations, artifacts...), so you'd need to sync those (if you're lucky, the filesystem does that for you)

Comment: Since you are referring to jenkins too, this answer might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794566/jenkins-failover-strategy